# GA4: Segment ordering in custom table reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I`m using custom table reports in analytics 4. I created segments (Web/Android) and add them to "First column". But they are totally mixed up. Any idea how to keep that together? This can`t be how it is intended. Or do I oversee something?

[image]